# Is my AWS QuickSight manifest file syntax correct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have an S3 bucket where I have the following file.

- abcd120121.csv
- abcd120121.csv.headless
- abcd120121.csv.headless.out
- abcd120121.metadata

"abcd120121.csv.headless" and "abcd120121.headless.out" are also CSV files, but one doesn't have the CSV header, and the other one is an output file. So I create the final file "abcd120121.csv" by combining both the files.

So the file for QuickSight is - "abcd120121.csv". QuickSight Imports it correctly, but QuickSight also imports the "abcd120121.csv.headless". This one doesn't have the CSV header.

My Manifest looks like below :

```
{
    "fileLocations": [
        {
            "URIPrefixes": [
                "s3://mys3bucket-230921-datas3bucket-1c6ifmdz9ctv9/nightly-transform/"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "globalUploadSettings": {
        "format": "CSV",
        "delimiter": ",",
        "textqualifier": "\"",
        "containsHeader": "true"
    }
}
```

My manifest file seems to be ok - How do I ensure QuickSight forcefully check if the file has Header or not before importing? I have also added ".headless" at the end of the other file - still no luck. Is there anything wrong with my manifest.json file?

Thanks again for your Advice?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using URIPrefixes rather than specifying URIs in fileLocations? I would assume because this scenario is the same for multiple files?

Comment: This is because the file name will change as I am creating the file every night. If I specify the filename then I have to overwrite the same file. Another process back-up the daily file to another S3 bucket. I thought manifest.json will actually look for "containHeader" = true - but I think they are using it on the quicksight end as field name.

Comment: Ah I see, so it probably is considering the first row of the data as the "header" in the headless case. Is there a way you could have a different prefix on the 2 files that combine to make the final CSV? Thats the only elegant way I can think of

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @occamatic I will try it and update here. Hopefully it will work :)

Comment: Confirming prefix changes didn't do the trick. manifest.json just checks if the file content-type is CSV and imports it. Anyway I will move the final file to a new s3 location and this will be something for QuickSight team to resolve in the future.